# Bundling Jquery and other modules with webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, webpack

Noob here (also couldn't find proper documentation).
So I was trying to implement gulp.js with jekyll. In order to do so, I wanted to concat javascript files into a single bundle. Now I can do that by hand, hard-coding every dependency and piping it through gulp-concat. But, I found out webpack does this thing pretty neatly. (PS: I was following https://ixkaito.github.io/frasco/). So now I installed webpack via npm, and tried to run my site, but it threw uncaught expression error. My directory tree is like this:

```
-js
----vendor
-------jquery.js
-------anime.js
----other
-------some-other-js-files.js
...
-main.js
```

Now I want to make bundle.js files using this, so that webpack can automatically detect the correct dependency and import it. Am I supposed to `require('jquery')` and do the same for all dependency in main.js?

My webpack config is

```
entry: [
      "main.js",
    ]
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the full error that you're getting? Also, may you please upload the entire webpack config file and your package.json

Comment: I am using the default settings provided in [this repo](https://github.com/ixkaito/frasco) (I have cloned the repo and directly ran `bundle exec npm start`. I am not getting any compilation errors, but chrome debugger shows that 'unreferenced element $jquery' which simply means that my jquery code is placed after my script code. Please have a look at the repo. Thanks for quick reply :D